# Error In Displaying Message When There Is An Attachment

Tags: error

I am trying to display an error message in SharePoint 2013. I added the following code inside my ItemAdding() event receiver to force it to have error:

```
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
properties.ErrorMessage = "test";
```

It works okay, I can see the error message.
[image]

However, when I attach any files, and try again, after saving, the attachment will disappear. When I attach again, I will get a server error:
[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Sandboxed Solution?

try this which is a similar question on Stack Overflow and is answered:
[Sharepoint event receiver and linq to sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13579977/1104271)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
               properties.ErrorMessage = "test";
               properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
               properties.Cancel = true;
```

You can also handling your attachment event with SPItemEventReceiver.ItemAttachmentAdding method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemattachmentadding.aspx

Comment: Its showing the error message "test" as required. So whats the issue exactly?

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't show the "test" when there is an attachment... It displays a server error message instead.

Comment: You can try  public override void ItemAttachmentAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) for attachment events : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx

Comment: The server error only happens when there is attachment. If there is no attachment, the error message is displayed properly.

Comment: Have you tried new ItemAttachmentAdded event?

Comment: Yes, it didn't pass the code inside.

Comment: I don't understand. It's firing or not?

Comment: No, it didn't fire at all. I added a breakpoint inside.

Comment: It should fire? You need to check why it is not firing? And just to clarify you want the error on Additem page? Actually in the server message its showing the correct messgae.

Comment: I am just confused why if there is no attachment, the error (which i intentionally created) is displayed properly (the red error message below the page). If there is an attachment, the error is displayed via server error page (not friendly). I want the error message to be displayed the same way with or without attachment.

Comment: Actually it took some time to actually attach the item. So there is separate event for that. The item added is fired when item is added but attachment is not yet uploaded.